# How should i communicate with my component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new player of pure Reactjs , i have a question in my case below :

My material include navComponent.js, stackComponent.js, nav.js

I want the nav.js data is get from stackComponent.js pass to navComponent.js, and then render the DOM in navComponent i want. Because the nav.js data, i need to reuse for another components in the furture. As the below code, i think i use this wrong react concept. How should i do in CORRECT React way.

In Header of index.html include

```
<script src="react/react.js"></script>
<script src="react/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="react/browser.min.js"></script>
```

In Body of index.html include

```
<div id="stackWrapper"></div>
```

In Footer of index.html include

```
<!-- Data -->
<script src="js/nav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Components -->
<script src="components/navComponent.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="components/stackComponent.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

In navComponent.js

```
window.NotesList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
          <nav className="pages-nav">
          {
            React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
                return <div>{child}</div>;
            })
          }
          </nav>
      );
  }
});
```

In stackComponent.js

```
var StackWrapper = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
      return (
          <div>
              <NotesList>
                  {
                      navItems.map(function(value, key){
                          console.log(key);
                          return <div key={key}>{value.title.name}</div>
                      })
                  }
              </NotesList>
          </div>
      )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <StackWrapper />,
  document.getElementById('stackWrapper')
);
```

In nav.js

```
var navItems = [
  {
      title: {
          name: 'home',
      },
      data: {
          link: {
              src: 'page-home'
          }
      }
  },
  {
      title: {
          name: 'docu',
      },
      data: {
          link: {
              src: 'page-docu'
          }
      }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass navItems as props to stackWrapper:

In stackComponent.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <StackWrapper navItems={navItems} />,
    document.getElementById('stackWrapper')
 );
```

In stackComponent.js, You can pass navItems using:

```
<NotesList navItems={this.props.navItems}>..</NoteList>
```

In navComponent.js, You can collect navItems using:

```
this.props.navItems
```

Comment: How about in the navComponent.js return element with this.props.navItems ?

Comment: why I can't return <div></div> in a navComponent.js ?

Comment: @tommychoo you could try like  return this.props.navItems.map(function(navItem){}); in navComponent.js it should work.

Comment: Thx, it works, what's the meaning of navItems={navItems} in stackComponent.js ?

Comment: navItem={navItems} binds the javascript variable navItems  (RHS) where you are storing json data to the react component props and hence you can access navItems variable in React Component using this.props.navItems

Comment: Thx, i still have a problem about render component. Suppose the component render nav item, how should i do if i want to get the dom object data, length....  like document.queryselector(selector) because my first choice i don't want to use ReactDOM.findDOMNode.

Comment: You should not use document.querySelector, you should try to  do as much as possible with state or props.like this.props.navItems.length instead of querying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110231/discussion-between-tommychoo-and-dhananjaya-kuppu).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a rule ok. The better and [recommended approach](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html), is using events. You can dispatch an event from some component and receive the update at any place you need.

You don't need to implement a entire [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) based application to solve this, you can for example, use the event api of browsers or use a [custom dispatcher](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html)

In case your components are in same tree, you can update the state and pass state's props as argument to the children components.

Comment: Wah. you are so quick to reply. Would you like to add a jsfiddle demo ?